# How to create a repository from certain files with svn?

Tags: linux, svn, svnserve

I'm using **subversion**, how to do this:

import files under `/target` but excluding those under `/target/download1` and `/target/download2`

Anyone can provide a demo?

Comment: Please consider revisiting some of your questions. Mark things as accepted if you have received a useful answer, or add comments or revise your questions with any additional details so we can get more of your questions resolved.

Comment: Similar answer solved at stackoverflow.com: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736856/svnignore-property-during-import

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty solution:

- Move `/target/download1` and `/target/download2` to `/tmp`
- `svn import /target http:/url.to.your.repo/trunk/path`
- If necessary, move `download1` and `download2` back to `/target`

The last step is probably not necessary, since your `/target` directory will not be under version control afterwards, you will need to checkout to a new directory anyway, this will then have your desired structure.